# About distribution certificate (with private key) in keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I understand that in iOS app development, for team collaboration, the leaving developer should export the distribution certificate from his keychain app because only his Macbook has the private key used as code signing identity. (*Please correct me if I am wrong here.*)

**My questions are:**

**1. Am I right that** the distribution provisioning profile for app store & the provisioning profile for ad-hoc distribution using the same code signing identity?

**2. Am I right that** if we lost the contact of leaving developer who has distributed the app to Apple Store, I can just delete the distribution certificate & corresponding distribution provisioning profile in Apple Developer account , and create a new distribution certificate & profile on my Macbook so that I have the new signing identity in my keychain, I don't need the leaving developer to export his, because the distribution certificate & profile is only used to distribute the app to Apple store or do ad-hoc distribution? Is there any harmful consequence I missed if do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1

Yes, distribution certificate is used for uploading app to apple store. And development for running on device or sending build.

For question 2

Yes, you can simply revoke his certificate. And create new one. That way your previous developer certificate are not required. Moreover, he wont be able to use them anymore and you can create new one and keep your certificate on apple developer account clean.

Hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: Thanks @cole, just to be sure, by doing so it won't affect the app the previous developer has released out to Apple store right? And I can continue update the app in the store by using my new distribution certificate, right?

Comment: Yes, certificate only affect when you start sending new build or upload new version or update  to apple store.

Comment: Please accept my answer, if you are happy with it !!